# Color a table row with style="color:#fff" for displaying in an email

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

We would like to display order details as table in an email

```
​<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>blah blah</td>
            <td>blah blah</td>
            <td>blah blah</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

We would ideally want the header to have background-color as '#5D7B9D' and text-color as '#fff'.
We are using `bgcolor='#5D7B9D'` for changing the background-color and are unable to find an alternative to do the same for changing the text-color.
As most of the email providers strip the CSS, we cannot use `style` attribute at all.

The questions are

1. How to make the header text appear in white?
2. Are there any alternate methods?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

you can easily do like this:-

```
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th bgcolor="#5D7B9D"><font color="#fff">Header 1</font></th>
          <th bgcolor="#5D7B9D"><font color="#fff">Header 2</font></th>
           <th bgcolor="#5D7B9D"><font color="#fff">Header 3</font></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>blah blah</td>
            <td>blah blah</td>
            <td>blah blah</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/VWdxj/7/

Comment: +1: I ended up doing this. all obslete tags :) makes my head spin. any good alternatives?

Answer (score 42):

For email templates, inline CSS is the properly used method to style:

```
<thead>
    <tr style="color: #fff; background: black;">
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: OP This should be the chosen answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use the `<font>` tag

```
​<table> 
    <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th><font color="#FFF">Header 1</font></th> 
            <th><font color="#FFF">Header 1</font></th> 
            <th><font color="#FFF">Header 1</font></th> 
        </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
        <tr> 
            <td>blah blah</td> 
            <td>blah blah</td> 
            <td>blah blah</td> 
        </tr> 
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

But I think this should work, too:

```
​<table> 
    <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th color="#FFF">Header 1</th> 
            <th color="#FFF">Header 1</th> 
            <th color="#FFF">Header 1</th> 
        </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
        <tr> 
            <td>blah blah</td> 
            <td>blah blah</td> 
            <td>blah blah</td> 
        </tr> 
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

**EDIT:**

Crossbrowser solution:

use capitals in HEX-color.

```
<th bgcolor="#5D7B9D" color="#FFFFFF"><font color="#FFFFFF">Header 1</font></th>
```

Comment: Updated with a crossbrowser solution. Tested it in fiddle. it should work. http://jsfiddle.net/VWdxj/10/

Comment: +1: thanks. much appreciated. i was mentioning that your second example doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using direct tags, you can edit the css attribute for the  color so that any tables you make will have the same color header text.

```
thead {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```